# jQuery set `background-size` does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

*I got the following problem:*

---

On click I am trying to animate the position, width and height of an absolute positioned div. Additionally I am trying to change the `background-size` through jQuery.

What happens is that it changes all the CSS properties correctly, but not `background-size`. 
It's supposed to change `background-size:100% auto` to `background-size:auto 100%`. It just seems to ignore that.

Does anyone know why this problem occurs?

```js
$(".item").click(function(){
  $(this).animate({
    'width': '94vw',
    'height': '94vh',
    'top': '3vh',
    'left': '3vw',
    'background-size': 'auto 100%'
  }, 500);
  
  $(".again").fadeIn();
});

$('.again').click(function() {
    location.reload();
});
```

```css
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.item{
  background:#a0a0a0;
  width:50%;
  height:100px;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  cursor:pointer;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-image:url("http://www.stefan-hefele.de/tl_files/Portfolio/Landschaft/Mallorca/Hochformate/9542_Mallorca%20Dawn.jpg");
  background-size:100% auto;
  background-position:center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.again{
display:none;
position:absolute;
bottom:20px;
width:100px;
left:calc(50% - 50px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item"></div>

<button class="again">Again</button>
```

Comment: I don't know if the same applies to jQuery animations, but in CSS at least `auto` is not a value that can be animated.

Comment: in jQuery, I think you need to pass JS CSSProperty names and not plain CSS ones, so it should be `backgroundSize` and not `backgound-size` (in the JS part only)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Totally forgot about that. They should really add that to CSS :(

Comment: @casraf You can do both. With quotiation marks `'background-size'` works. Without them, you have to use `backgroundSize`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use CSS transitions combined with a class instead of jQuery `animate()` ?

Here I use the class `.big` to toggle your CSS rules. I also added `transition: all .5s;` on your `.item` to enable transitions.

```js
$(".item").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('big');
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.item {
  background: #a0a0a0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url("http://www.stefan-hefele.de/tl_files/Portfolio/Landschaft/Mallorca/Hochformate/9542_Mallorca%20Dawn.jpg");
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.item.big {
  width: 94vw;
  height: 94vh;
  top: 3vh;
  left: 3vw;
  background-size: auto 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's working. I tried to change it in jQuery to keep every CSS change in the same place.